# What are the best ways to compare numerical and exact solutions in 3D plots?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, numerics

What are the best ways to comparing numerical and exact solutions in 3D plots?
For example, suppose that I have have numerical and exact solutions as follows:

```
uexact[x_, t_] := x*t;
unumeric[x_, t_] := 0.0000001 + x*t; 
Plot3D[{unumeric[x, t], uexact[x, t]}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

- I often come across 3d plots as follows. How can I create a 3D comparison plot like this?

[image]

- What hat are your suggestions as an alternative for the comparison?

Comment: I think plotting the difference can give you a more accurate picture about the errors.

Comment: To reproduce the plot use `Show[ Plot3D[ uexact[x, t], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2}], Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[ Flatten[ Table[{x, t, unumeric[x, t]}, {x, 0, 2, 0.125}, {t, 0, 2, 0.125}], 1]]}]]`

Comment: It's what I look for. Thank you @BobHanlon. Lastly. how to add the legends?

Comment: `Legended[ Show[ Plot3D[ uexact[x, t], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[ {HoldForm[ uexact[x, t]]}]], Graphics3D[ {AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[ Flatten[ Table[{x, t, unumeric[x, t]}, {x, 0, 2, 0.125}, {t, 0, 2, 0.125}], 1]]}],
AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, t, u})], PointLegend[{Black}, {HoldForm[unumeric[x, t]]}, LegendMarkerSize -> 12]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the numeric function approximates the exact solution closely, then the difference will probably be imperceptible in comparing the plots of each.  One could use `ColorFunction` to visualize the error on the plot of either `uexact` or `unumeric`.  The easiest way to me is a two/three-step process: Plot the function with a fine grid (higher `PlotPoints`) and a random `ColorFunction`, use the data from the plot to compute the error on the plot grid, and replace the colors in the plot by a gradient depending on the error.

I saved each computational step, more or less, in a variable, in case you want to inspect the intermediate results.

```
ClearAll[uexact, unumeric, x, y, t];
uexact[x_, t_] := (1 + (x - 1)^3)*Sin[Pi t + x];
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, t, uexact[x, t]}, {x, 0., 2., 1/2.}, {t, 0., 2., 1/4.}], 
   1];
unumeric = Interpolation[data];
plot = Plot3D[unumeric[x, t], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotPoints -> 50];
pts = First@Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[p_, ___] :> p, Infinity];
unum = pts[[All, 3]];                (* values of unumeric[x, t] *)
uex = uexact @@@ pts[[All, {1, 2}]]; (* values of exact[x, t] *)
du = unum - uex;                     (* errors (absolute) *)
max = Max@Abs[du];        (* for scaling error because... *)
scerr = 0.5 + 0.5 du/max; (* color functions' domains are [0, 1] *)
plot = Legended[          (* recolor plot according to scerr *)
 plot /. 
  HoldPattern[VertexColors -> _List] -> 
   VertexColors -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"] /@ scerr),
 BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {-max, max}}]
 ]
```

[image]

Since the example I chose is an interpolation, the relationship to the interpolation grid is significant.  We can add it to the plot above:

```
Show[plot, Graphics3D[{PointSize@Medium, Point@data}]]
```

[image]

Comment: It's what I look for. Thank you very much. Lastly. how to add the legends?

Comment: @RF_1 I added my legend with `Legended[]`, using the range computed for scaling `scerr`. It’s in the first code block above. Or did you mean some other legend?

Comment: In fact, I mean that `PointLegend` and `SwatchLegend` in order to explain which one is the uexact or unumeric.